# How can I modify what controls show up for my VideoView?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I have a VideoView controlled by a simple MediaController that I'd like to modify the controls for. Currently, it shows a seek bar, fast-forward and rewind buttons, and play/pause. I'd like to narrow this down to simply having play and pause buttons, as the stream I'm playing is more or less live. How can I modify the controls present? This is my current code in `onCreate`:

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

this.videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
this.mediaController = new MediaController(this);
this.mediaController.setAnchorView(this.videoView);

Uri uri = Uri.parse(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("uri"));

this.videoView.setMediaController(this.mediaController);
this.videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

this.videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        findViewById(R.id.video_loading_spinner).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});

this.videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        showDialog(VIDEO_FAILED);
        return true;
    }
});

//this.videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
//  @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
//      showDialog(VIDEO_COMPLETE);
//  }
//});

this.videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the controls that are present in `MediaController`, but you can create your own controller and use that instead of `MediaController`. I did that in [this ancient project](https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry).